# Differences between (command) and command in bash

Tags: bash, time, subshell

While investigating the problem of redirecting the `stderr` of the `bash` keyword `time` and the standard solution to the problem, I came across another question.
The description `man bash` gives of the `(list)` *compound command* is *list is executed in a subshell environment*. Now, as you can see from the execution of the little program `hello`- which makes the simple `system("ps -opid,ppid,comm")` call, it looks there is no difference at all between the `(./hello)` and `./hello` command lines. That came as a surprise to me. However I understand there is a difference when the command is a built-in one. In this case, with no parentheses no fork will take place but one would with the parentheses around the built-in command. Am I missing anything?

```
18:59:13 -> echo $$
5323
19:34:30 -> ./hello
hello world from process ID 8657, parent ID 5323
  PID  PPID COMM
 5323  5322 -bash
 8657  5323 ./hello
19:42:34 -> (./hello)
hello world from process ID 8977, parent ID 5323
  PID  PPID COMM
 5323  5322 -bash
 8977  5323 ./hello
19:42:43 -> time (./hello)
hello world from process ID 8985, parent ID 8984
  PID  PPID COMM
 5323  5322 -bash
 8984  5323 -bash
 8985  8984 ./hello

real    0m0.021s
user    0m0.003s
sys 0m0.004s
19:42:53 -> (time ./hello)
hello world from process ID 9000, parent ID 8999
  PID  PPID COMM
 5323  5322 -bash
 8999  5323 -bash
 9000  8999 ./hello

real    0m0.030s
user    0m0.003s
sys 0m0.005s
19:43:05 ->
```

Answer (score 2):

A subshell isn't guaranteed to run in a separate process. That's just the usual implementation.

The definition of a subshell is that shell must ensure that the subshell doesn't change the state of its parent: it must not affect the parent's variables, defined functions, aliases, options, history, limits, etc. The easiest way to do that is to run the subshell in a separate process, so that's usually what happens. But if the shell can be sure that the subshell won't affect anything in the parent, it doesn't have to run a separate process.

With most sh implementations, a subshell that does nothing but run an external command doesn't fork twice.

```
for sh in dash bash ksh93 mksh zsh; do printf "%6s " "$sh"; "$sh" -c '(perl -e "print getppid()"); echo " $$"'; done
  dash 945 945
  bash 947 947
 ksh93 949 949
  mksh 951 951
   zsh 953 953
```

As soon as you do something more complicated, bash forks for the subshell and forks again for the external command. Some other shells don't fork for the last command of a (sub)shell (unless there's a trap).

```
for sh in dash bash ksh93 mksh zsh; do printf "%6s " "$sh"; "$sh" -c '(true; perl -e "print getppid()"); echo " $$"'; done
  dash 1306 1306
  bash 1309 1308
 ksh93 1311 1311
  mksh 1314 1313
   zsh 1316 1316
```

ATT ksh (`ksh93`) optimizes more than other shells. Of the five I ran in my comparison, it's the only one that optimizes by creating a separate data structure in the same process to keep track of changing data in the subshell.

```
for sh in dash bash ksh93 mksh zsh; do printf "%6s " "$sh"; "$sh" -c '(perl -e "print getppid()"; /bin/true); echo " $$"'; done
  dash 3082 3081
  bash 3085 3084
 ksh93 3088 3088
  mksh 3092 3091
   zsh 3096 3095
```

There are things that force even ATT ksh to create a subprocess for the subshell, for example changing a process limit.

```
for sh in dash bash ksh93 mksh zsh; do printf "%6s " "$sh"; "$sh" -c '(ulimit -n 42; perl -e "print getppid()"; /bin/true); echo " $$"'; done
  dash 4504 4503
  bash 4507 4506
 ksh93 4511 4510
  mksh 4515 4514
   zsh 4519 4518
```

Comment: Understood. Still I don't get what's the point in saying *list is executed in a subshell environment* when `(list)` and `list` are processed exactly in the same way.

Comment: @diciotto In general, `(list)` and `list` are not processed in the same way. Compare `a=out; (a=in); echo $a` and `a=out; a=in; echo $a`. In the specific case where `list` is a single external command, they are processed in the same way, because in this specific case there's no observable difference except for the PID.

Comment: OK, thanks. That's why I wrote "I understand there would be a difference if the command were a built-in one" (just as in the example you made).